# Do UTF-16 or UTF-32 have byte values in the non-printable ASCII range when encoding characters outside the ASCII range?

Tags: unicode

I'm looking to take some shortcuts when looking for non-printable ASCII characters in raw byte streams of text encoded using Unicode encoding schemes.

I know for instance that in UTF-8 encoding, if a character is encoded using multiple bytes, each byte will always be => 128, therefore if a byte has a value of < 32 I know it's a non-printable ASCII character. I want to know if I can take similar shortcuts with UTF-16 and UTF-32.

I know UTF-16 and UTF-32 use zero padding for encoded ASCII characters, but wanted to know if individual bytes in non-ASCII range characters could ever be less than 32.

Basically I would like to know if I can scan bytes for ASCII characters below 32 reliably (as I can with UTF-8), without having to decode the stream into characters.

For reference I'm looking for line breaks (10, 13) to index text into lines, and looking at optimal ways of doing this i.e. without decoding into characters.

Comment: There are no bytes in utf-32, every codepoint is *exactly* 32-bits.  I think you meant utf-16 instead of "Unicode".

Comment: @Hans Thanks yes, utf-32 is 32 bits, I'm dealing with byte streams though and looking for shortcuts without dealing with characters for performance reasons.

Comment: @Hans I'm always confused as to whether to call UTF-16, Unicode or UTF-16. I always used to call it UTF-16, but then when I started using C# the encoding is called "Unicode". Should I be referring to it as UTF-16? Thanks.

Comment: @TimLloyd: Yes, you should. **Unicode** is the actual character set. **UTFs** are byte encodings of Unicode. When Microsoft refers to Unicode as an encoding, they mean **UTF-16LE**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-32 is a straightforward, no-frills encoding. Each character is represented directly by its 32-bit codepoint. There is no provision like there is with UTF-8 that ASCII bytes will never be found in the middle of non-ASCII characters. Any codepoint of the form `\uxxxxxx10`, `\uxxxx10xx`, `\uxx10xxxx`, or `\u10xxxxxx` will contain the byte `0x10` when "encoded" as UTF-32.

However, because every character is always a full 32 bits, you *can* read the stream in 4-byte chunks and look the 4-byte value `0x00000010` or `0x00000013`.

Comment: Very nice, should have thought of that myself :) Do you know if I use a similar technique with Unicode and read 2 bytes, whether I could get false positives with surrogate pairs?

Comment: 2-byte values belonging to a surrogate pair are always in the `0xD800-0xDBFF` and `0xDC00-0xDFFF` ranges, otherwise those Unicode codepoins would not have been encoded using surrogates in the first place. As you can see, there are `0x00` bytes present, so you have to take both bytes of a surrogate high/low value into account.